# How to count the unchecked checkboxes in a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT status, vendor FROM tbl_softwareinstalled WHERE vendor NOT LIKE ''");
$nums = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo "<form name = 'filter' action='softwarefilter.php' method='POST'>
$nums<br>

<table border = 1><tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><strong>Software Vendor</strong></td></tr>";

$ctr1 = 1;
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$vendor = $fetch['vendor'];
$status = $fetch['status'];
    if(($ctr1 % 2)==1)
        { print "<tr bgcolor = 'white'>";}
        else 
        { print "<tr bgcolor = '#EEEEEE'>"; }
    print "<td><input name= 'chk[]' type='hidden' value='0'>
    <input type = 'checkbox' name = 'chk[]' value = '$vendor' ";




    if ($status == 'Enabled') {
    print "checked = 'checked'></td><td>$vendor</td></tr>"; }
    else {
    print "></td><td>$vendor</td></tr>"; }
    $ctr1++;
}
print "</table>";
print "<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'Update Filter'>
</form> ";


$submit = $_POST['submit'];
if(isset($submit))
{ 
    $chk = $_POST['chk'];
    $count = count($chk);

    if (empty($chk)) {

    echo "qweqwe<br>";
    }

        for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
        $abc = $chk[$i];
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_softwareinstalled SET status = 'Enabled' WHERE vendor = '$abc'");

        }

    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.5;url=/assets/softwarefilter.php">
            <script language="javascript">
            alert("Software filter updated.");
            </script>';
}
```

Hi, how can I count the UNCHECKED CHECKBOXES in a while loop with this block of code? 
Let's say for example I have 10 checkboxes with 10 values, the user checked 3 checkboxes (with values: 'abc', 'def', 'ghi'), after submitting it. It will count all the UNCHECKED checkboxes and echoes the value of it. The values of 3 checked checkboxes SHOULD NOT be echoed.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will only tell you which have been *checked*. Pull *all* the possible boxes from your database, and then *remove* those that the browser has told you are checked.

Answer (score 0):

I had worked on a similar thing for counting unchecked boxes.
place two input fields of input type checkbox and input type hidden with different names

```
<input type="hidden" class="" name="test[]" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="" name="checkbox[]" value="1">
```

then on submit

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $cnt = array();
    $counter =0;
    $testcnt = 0;
    $cnt = 0;
    if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
        $testcnt = count($_POST['test']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
        $cnt = count($_POST['checkbox']);
    }
    echo 'the count of unchecked boxes is ';
    print_r($testcnt-$cnt);
}
```

For your case change this to:

```
<input name= 'unchecked[]' type='hidden' value='0'>
```

then on submit when your checking for isset(submit) you can add the following an d change accordingly

```
$unchecked_input = count($_POST['unchecked']);
$chk = $_POST['chk'];
$count = count($chk);
echo $unchecked_input-$count; //will output the count of unchecked boxes
```